# how can save value with SharePreference Android

Tags: java, android

hi everyone i am looking to use SharePreference to save values of calculations. i want each time pressing "=" will save the value of the calculation in the form tvMath = tvResult which I don't know how to do now.

After saving I want to show it on Another screen

this is my code

Main Activity

```
package com.khuongviettai.caculatorsharedpreferences;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.mozilla.javascript.Context;
import org.mozilla.javascript.Scriptable;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private TextView tvMath, tvResult;
    private Button btnC, btnOpen, btnClose, btnDiv, btn7, btn8, btn9, btnMul, btn4, btn5, btn6, btnSub, btn1, btn2, btn3, btnPlus, btn0, btnDot, btnResult, btnBack;



    private String currentMath = "";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        tvMath = findViewById(R.id.tvMath);
        tvResult = findViewById(R.id.tvResult);
        assignID(btnC, R.id.btnC);
        assignID(btnOpen, R.id.btnOpen);
        assignID(btnClose, R.id.btnClose);
        assignID(btnDiv, R.id.btnDiv);
        assignID(btn0, R.id.btn0);
        assignID(btn1, R.id.btn1);
        assignID(btn2, R.id.btn2);
        assignID(btn3, R.id.btn3);
        assignID(btn4, R.id.btn4);
        assignID(btn5, R.id.btn5);
        assignID(btn6, R.id.btn6);
        assignID(btn7, R.id.btn7);
        assignID(btn8, R.id.btn8);
        assignID(btn9, R.id.btn9);
        assignID(btnMul, R.id.btnMul);
        assignID(btnSub, R.id.btnSub);
        assignID(btnPlus, R.id.btnPlus);
        assignID(btnDot, R.id.btnDot);
        assignID(btnResult, R.id.btnResult);
        assignID(btnBack, R.id.btnBack);




    }

    void assignID(Button btn, int id) {
        btn = findViewById(id);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }




    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Button button = (Button) view;
        String buttonText = button.getText().toString();
        if (buttonText.equals("=")) {
            if (currentMath.equals("")) {
                tvResult.setText("0");
                return;
            }
            String finalResult = getResult(currentMath);
            if (!finalResult.equals("Err")) {


                tvResult.setText(finalResult);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                tvResult.setText("Err");
            }
            return;

        } else if (buttonText.equals("C")) {
            tvMath.setText("");
            tvResult.setText("0");
            currentMath = "";
            return;

        } else if (buttonText.equals("BACK")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HistoryActivity.class);

            startActivity(intent);
            return;

        }

        currentMath += buttonText;
        tvMath.setText(currentMath);
    }




    String getResult(String data) {
        try {
            Context context = Context.enter();
            context.setOptimizationLevel(-1);
            Scriptable scriptable = context.initStandardObjects();
            String finalResult = context.evaluateString(scriptable, data, "Javascript", 1, null).toString();
            if (finalResult.endsWith(".0")) {
                finalResult = finalResult.replace(".0", "");
            }
            if (data.equals("16052001")) {
                finalResult = "I love Tai";
            }
            return finalResult;
        } catch (Exception e
        ) {
            return "Err";
        }
    }
```

HistoryActivity

```
package com.khuongviettai.caculatorsharedpreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class HistoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_history);

        listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);

    }
}
```

the above code when I press BACK will switch to HistoryActyvity

[image: image app]